# MiniShift failing to Deploy Simple Java App

Tags: openshift, minishift

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to deploy a simple Java app on the latest version of Minishift (Version 1.34.1) which i'm running locally using Windows 10 and VirtualBox
and seeing the error above.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get this resolved?

Comment: Can you please show the previous step as well. What configuration have you provided?

Comment: I'm trying to deloy a Java application using a Demo Project i just created. When i select Java as the language, then select Wildfly and click next and then enter the configs in the picture attached i see the error.

Comment: If you select any previous version of widlfly does it return same error?

Comment: Yes, when i try deploying anything it fails with the same error.  I'm using a Proxy and think it must be related to that.   I tried starting minishift using the following command but still seeing the same issue: `minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=myProxy:myPort --docker-env NO_PROXY=192.168.99.101 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=myProxy:myPort`

Comment: Yeah, definetely it's about proxy... Try removing the `--docker-env` from your start command, use instead `$ minishift start --http-proxy http://YOURPROXY:PORT --https-proxy https://YOURPROXY:PORT` or in any case add those `--http-proxy` options to your startup command.